# Update form not working at all in many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle

In my app there is a many-to-many relationship between recipe and ingredient, everything is working fine but update.

When I update a recipe, i can update any value associated to recipe table in my database but ingredients are not modified

Here is the recipe model

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_create :save_implementos
    after_create :save_ingredientes
    has_many :HasImplemento, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :HasIngrediente, dependent: :destroy


has_many :ingredientes, through: :HasIngrediente
has_many :implementos, through: :HasImplemento


    #CUSTOM SETTER#
def ingredientes=(value)
        @ingredientes = value
end

def implementos=(value)
        @implementos = value
        #raise @implementos.to_yaml
end


private

#Guarda los implemenos de una receta
def save_implementos
    #raise self.id.to_yaml
    @implementos.each do |implemento_id|
        HasImplemento.create(implemento_id: implemento_id, recipe_id: self.id) 
    end
end

def save_ingredientes
    #raise @ingredientes.to_yaml
    @ingredientes.each do |ingrediente_id|
        HasIngrediente.create(ingrediente_id: ingrediente_id, recipe_id: self.id)
    end

end
```

Here is the ingredient model

```
class Ingrediente < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :has_ingredientes
    has_many :recipes, through: :HasIngrediente
end
```

and Here is the join table

```
class HasIngrediente < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :recipe
  belongs_to :ingrediente
end
```

Comment: Why have you got the custom setters? They don't look like they do anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in your Recipe model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients
```

Comment: think so, there's no controller info detailed, for update, but make sure you pass the :id of the ingredients in the strong parameters settings. That always gets me on update.. I get it working for create, and then wonder why update never works.

Answer (score 0):

Your models have a lot of [non-conventional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convention_over_configuration) code, which is likely the reason for them not working as required:

1. Use [`snake_case`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) to define your associations (not [`CamelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase))
2. If you're saving nested/associated data, use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html)
3. Only use callbacks to deal with the model directly; not to deal with other models

---

```
#app/models/recipe.rb
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredientes
    has_and_belongs_to_many :implementos 

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredientes, :implementos #-> if you wanted to create new ones
end
```

Because you're only creating join table records with your callbacks, you can get away with using `<<` or populating the [`collection_singular_ids`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) value (*if* you're using existing records):

```
#app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @recipe = Recipe.new recipe_params
      @recipe.save
   end

   private

   def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:implementos_ids, :ingredientes_ids)
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use:

```
#app/views/recipes/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :implementos_ids, Implementos.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.collection_select :ingredientes_ids, Ingrediente.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

-

I recommend `has_and_belongs_to_many` because it does not appear that you're populating your join table with any more data than the two model references.

The [difference between `has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many) is `has_many :through` gives you the ability to store extra data in the join table. If you don't need this, `has_and_belongs_to_many` is far simpler to maintain.

Thus, to answer your question directly, to update your `recipe`, you can use the following (with my updated code):

```
#app/views/recipes/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @recipe do |f| %>
   <%= f.collection_select :implementos_ids, Implementos.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.collection_select :ingredientes_ids, Ingrediente.all, :id, :name %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

#app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb
class RecipesController < ApplicationController
   def edit
      @recipe = Recipe.find params[:id]
   end

   def update
      @recipe = Recipe.find params[:id]
      @recipe.update recipe_params
   end

   private

   def recipe_params
      params.require(:recipe).permit(:implementos_ids, :ingredientes_ids)
   end
end
```

This will set the `implementos_ids` & `ingredientes_ids` values for your `recipe`, which will update the associations automatically.